# When UITextField is editing, call setText will hang a while

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I am formatting text of UITextField when inputting. Code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *newString = nil;
    // format 'newString' here 
    [textField setText:newString];
    // move cursor
    return NO;
}
```

But `setText:` will hang for a while in main thread. Less text more time.

So, I tried below code, `resignFirstResponder` before `setText:`:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[textField resignFirstResponder];
[textField setText:newString];
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

It resolved the hang issue.

But why it will hang. And If there is any better solution.

Comment: What is newString, and why are you not declaring it as a NSString*? Where does "newtext" come from? Please provide the code you are using, because the method you've put in your question won't even compile.

Comment: `NSString *newString`?

Comment: @il3v, I have changed the code.

Comment: @danielhadar, I have changed the code.

Comment: The question is still not clear to me. What are you attempting to achieve? Exactly what code are you putting in "move cursor" and "format 'newstring' here"?

Answer (score 0):

What's `newText`? Do you mean `newString` (which you define as `nil`). Notice `UITextField`'s `text` isn't `nullable`.

Comment: hi, I have changed the code. And the `newString` is not `null`

Comment: You initialize `newString` as `nil`, and send it to `setText:`. It's as if you called `[textField setText:newString]` -- and notice that the `text` property of `UITextField` isn't `nullable`, so this behaviour is undefined.